# making squares in a raster

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to make a raster with mesh shape structure in it. this example is the sample. I want to rotate all square together in different angles later for my study it would be the building in a slope with I need to relocate them in so many cases

```
ymx = 0 + 30*1
Z <- matrix(0,nrow = 30, ncol =30)
Z = raster(Z,xmn=0,xmx=30,ymn=0,ymx=ymx)

for(i in 1:30) {
  x = 0 + 1*(i-0.5)
  for(j in 1:30) {
    y = ymx - 1*(j-0.5)
    Z[j,i] = 0 - 0.01*(y-ymx)
  }
}

R=c(1:3,7:9,13:15,19:21,25:27)
for(i in R) {
  for(j in R) {
   Z[j,i]=Z[j,i] + 0.3
  }
}
```

I need a pattern depends on my raster size as `ncol` and `nrow` instead of this: `R=c(1:3,7:9,13:15,19:21,25:27)`

The code above is the type of raster I need but its just manually i entered numbers I wanna do it with a pattern which able me to re_orient the mesh later.

[image: here] is how it should looks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the part of codes up there was the structure part. 
      R=c(1:3,7:9,13:15,19:21,25:27)
      for(i in R) {
       for(j in R) {
         Z[j,i]=Z[j,i] + 0.3
        }

Comment: I tried the code above but not so practical